# SQL REGEX not working like its expected to

Tags: regex, oracle, oracle19c

I'm having issues finding a solution for this

```
set serveroutput on;
declare
EmailRegexp CONSTANT VARCHAR2(1000) :='^[a-z0-9!#$%&''*+/=?^_`{|}~-]+(\.[a-z0-9!#$%&''*+/=?^_`{|}~-]+)*@([a-z0-9]([a-z0-9-]*[a-z0-9])?\.)+([A-Z]{2,})$';
p_vInEmailAddress VARCHAR2(30) := 'first@hotmail.net';

begin 
dbms_output.put_line('regex: '||LOWER(SUBSTR(REGEXP_SUBSTR(p_vInEmailAddress, '\.([^.\n\s]*)$'), 2))||''''); 
end;

--results:
--regex: '
--PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.

--now if i do this instead: 
p_vInEmailAddress VARCHAR2(30) := 'first@hotmail.com';
--I get results back

--PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.

--regex: com'
```

What am I doing wrong and why does it not like '.net' part?

How can I fix this?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problematic part of your query can be reduced to:

```sql
begin 
  dbms_output.put_line(
    REGEXP_SUBSTR(
      'first@hotmail.net',
      '\.([^.\n\s]*)$'
    )
  ); 
end;
/
```

The regular expression `\.([^.\n\s]*)$` is looking for:

1. A dot character `\.`; then
2. Zero-or-more characters that are not a dot `.` or a slash `\` or an `n` or a slash `\` or an `s`; then
3. The end-of-the-string.

The problem is that your string has an `n` character and the regular expression is excluding `n` as `\n` is interpreted as two characters and not the perl-like expression representing a single newline character. You want to replace `\n` with the `CHR(10)` character outside the string literal (or a newline inside it) and `\s` with the posix-expression `[:space:]`.

What you want is:

```sql
begin 
  dbms_output.put_line(
    REGEXP_SUBSTR(
      'first@hotmail.net',
      '\.([^.' || CHR(10) || '[:space:]]*)$'
    )
  ); 
end;
/
```

or

```sql
begin 
  dbms_output.put_line(
    REGEXP_SUBSTR(
      'first@hotmail.net',
      '\.([^.
[:space:]]*)$'
    )
  ); 
end;
/
```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_21&fiddle=11ebada974899e35f69de49371c6f6ea)*

Answer (score 0):

Just use

```sql
REGEXP_SUBSTR(p_vInEmailAddress,'\.([^.[:space:]]*)$')
```

`\s` does not match whitespace in character class in Oracle regex.

`[:space:]` matches both horizontal and vertical whitespace.

**EXPLANATION**

```sql
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  \.                       '.'
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  (                        group and capture to \1:
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    [^.[:space:]]*           any character except: '.', whitespace
                             characters (like \s) (0 or more times
                             (matching the most amount possible))
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  )                        end of \1
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  $                        before an optional \n, and the end of the
                           string
```